# how to use python re findall and regex so that 2 conditions can be run simultaneously?

Tags: python, regex

here my data string :

```
MYDATA=DATANORMAL
MYDATA=DATA_NOTNORMAL
```

i use this code, but when i run it it shows empty at `DATANORMAL`

```
mydata = re.findall(r'MYDATA=(.*)' r'_.*', mystring)
print mydata
```

and it just shows : `NOTNORMAL`

i want both to work, and displays data like this:

```
DATANORMAL
NOTNORMAL
```

how do i do it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove only `DATA_` prefix from words like `DATA_NOTNORMAL` or there are other prefixes to remove too? Like `INFO_NOTNORMAL` would need removing `INFO_` or not?

Comment: You should probably accept one of the answers (or post an answer of your own and accept that) and then post a new question with your updated requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYsrt7K4pCgzL13BVkFJSYnLN9LFMcTRFkT4@Qf5Ovogi8T7@YdARUFqgXpTEksSgTqLUvXSMvNSEnNyNIrU42KKtaCaNOyt9LTjNe019LTtNYHCKuo6CjALdUC6fDW5CoCcEg2IUZr//wMA)

```
import re

mystring = """
MYDATA=DATANORMAL
MYDATA=DATA_NOTNORMAL
"""

mydata = re.findall(r'^\s*MYDATA=(?:.+_)?(.+?)\s*$', mystring, re.M)
print(mydata)
```

In case if you need word before `_`, not after, then use regex `r'^\s*MYDATA=(.+?)(?:_.+)?\s*$'` in code above, you may [try this second variant here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYsrt7K4pCgzL13BVkFJSYnLN9LFMcTRFkT4@Qf5Ovogi8T7@YdARUFqgXpTEksSgTqLUvXSMvNSEnNyNIrU42KKtaCaNPS07TU17K3i9bQ17YHCKuo6CjALdUC6fDW5CoCcEg2IUZr//wMA).

Comment: yes this work but the opposite that i want, your script displays the data after the character `_`, what if I want to display the data before the character `_`?

Comment: @gmpsorg To capture string before `_` use this regex in my code `r'^\s*MYDATA=(.+?)(?:_.+)?\s*$'` you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYsrt7K4pCgzL13BVkFJSYnLN9LFMcTRFkT4@Qf5Ovogi8T7@YdARUFqgXpTEksSgTqLUvXSMvNSEnNyNIrU42KKtaCaNPS07TU17K3i9bQ17YHCKuo6CjALdUC6fDW5CoCcEg2IUZr//wMA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe, you might want to use an alternation here:

```
\bMYDATA=((?:DATA|(?:DATA_))\S+)\b
```

Script:

```
inp = "some text MYDATA=DATANORMAL more text MYDATA=DATA_NOTNORMAL"
mydata = re.findall(r'\bMYDATA=((?:DATA|(?:DATA_))\S+)\b', inp)
print(mydata)
```

This prints:

```
['DATANORMAL', 'DATA_NOTNORMAL']
```

Comment: The string you're working with appears a bit different from the "string" in the OP? Although I guess that may not matter, since the word boundary would still match the start correctly.

Comment: @cs95 Your profile is basically amazing...very few people who joined in the past 5 years have 60+ gold medals.  How did you manage to do it?

Comment: Very few folks in the past 5 years also have as many posts as I do, I consider it a mark of my participation over the years :)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : yes, but it can't be if "MYDATA=" arbitrary data, because my data is not the only two data.

Comment: Please check my question again, i have been update for details. Thanks

Comment: ...and I have reverted your question to the original one, since your recent edit invalidates all 3 answers you have already received.  Please do _not_ make substantial edits to your question after other users have already answered.

Comment: Why the extra parentheses around `(?:DATA_)`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add `flags=re.M`?

```
import re
mystring = """
MYDATA=DATANORMAL
MYDATA=DATA_NOTNORMAL"""

pattern = re.compile("MYDATA=(?:DATA_)?(\w+)",flags=re.M)
print(pattern.findall(mystring))
```

Comment: yes, but it can't be if `MYDATA=` arbitrary data, because my data is not the only two data.

Comment: Please check my question again, i have been update for details. Thanks